# Objective-C launch iTunes in background

Tags: objective-c, background, itunes, launch

I want to launch iTunes but i don't want the launch to be visible, at the moment the code i have navigates to the space which iTunes is assigned to and makes iTunes the key window, so effectively i want it to launch in the background.

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"iTunes"];
```

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use -launchApplicationAtURL:options:configuration:error: to launch it, and include NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide in the options.

Comment: Thanks, NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide worked iTunes was launched and not visible but my Mac still switches to the space that iTunes is assigned to, is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 4):

I *think* this is what you want:

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchAppWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes" options: NSWorkspaceLaunchDefault | NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation additionalEventParamDescriptor:nil launchIdentifier:nil];
```

The important bit is `NSWorkspaceLaunchWithoutActivation`.

Edit: As also posted, you can use NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide as well, if you want iTunes to be hidden.

Comment: Thanks, NSWorkspaceLaunchAndHide worked iTunes was launched and not visible but my Mac still switches to the space that iTunes is assigned to, is there anyway to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Should this work for you?

- (NSRunningApplication *)launchApplicationAtURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSWorkspaceLaunchOptions)options configuration:(NSDictionary *)configuration error:(NSError **)error

---

Comment: Did you think it would work better now than it did an hour ago? Or did you just not bother to read the existing answers before posting yours?